# Android SQLite unrecognized token on custom query

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to query my SQLite database and isolate the dataset sent to the cursor. Each record has a color field and I would like to query my data and return for a specific color.

When I run it, I get a SQLiteException: Unrecognized token "red"

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public Cursor getGroupRecords( String color ) {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, DATABASE_STRUCTURE, 
            KEY_COLOR + "=" + color, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
08-23 13:52:00.560: D/szipinf(14301): Initializing inflate state
08-23 13:52:00.560: D/szipinf(14301): Initializing zlib to inflate
08-23 13:52:00.970: I/Database(14301): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: red
08-23 13:52:00.980: D/AndroidRuntime(14301): Shutting down VM
08-23 13:52:00.980: W/dalvikvm(14301): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac0560)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cca.pqr/com.cca.pqr.PQRActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cca.pqr/com.cca.pqr.PQRListActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: red: , while compiling: SELECT _id, Color, Class, Subclass, Item, Value, Other, Remarks FROM PQR WHERE Color=red
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 13:52:00.990: E/AndroidRuntime(14301): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cca.pqr/com.cca.pqr.PQRListActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: red: , while compiling: SELECT _id, Color, Class, Subclass, Item, Value, Other, Remarks FROM PQR WHERE Color=red
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Here is the working code:

```
    public Cursor getGroupRecords( String color ) {

    final String SELECTION = KEY_COLOR + "=?";
    final String[] SELECTION_ARGS = { color };

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, DATABASE_STRUCTURE, 
            SELECTION, SELECTION_ARGS, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question, but I get a SQLiteException: unrecognized token "red"

Comment: ok. Thanks. It would help if we knew what the contents of the contants were. It just seems that your query isn't formatted properly. And also, I don't believe that you need all those extra null values. You should be able to stop at like 6. Try to use the slimmest query method you can find. (purely style and readability reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. Something is wrong with how you are building your query. Check out this example.

```
public static Cursor getItemWithColor(ContentResolver contentResolver, String color) {
    Uri uri = My.Table.CONTENT_URI;

    final String[] PROJECTION = {
            My.Table._ID, My.Table.COLOR
    };

    final String SELECTION = My.Table.COLOR + "=?";

    final String[] SELECTION_ARGS = {
            color
    };

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, PROJECTION, SELECTION, SELECTION_ARGS, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and found that it can be solved by containing the selection argument in quotes. Just using the standard selection argument field didn't seem to work for values containing both numbers and letters.

So the resulting query would be:

```
db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, DATABASE_STRUCTURE, 
        KEY_COLOR + "=\"" + color+"\"", null, null, null, null, null);
```